# Is it possible to deliver emails to a public folder

Tags: email, exchange-2003, public-folders

Is it possible for me to create a new email address and make all the emails go to a public folder i have exchange 2003 on my server at the moment. If this is possible what would be the best way for me to implement this solution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Create an email adress the alll mail ends up in public folder instead of personal mailbox

Comment: No what I meant was, are you wanting a bunch of different users to be able to see and respond to emails or?  I deliberately left off Public Folders because they're a management nightmare.  Are you currently using Public Folders or would you be turning them on just for this?

Comment: It's a long time since I used exchange 2003, but if I recall correctly you can simply "mail enable" them in the interface and job done. It's an absolute nightmare though - my default position for public folders these days is "don't... just don't".

Comment: we already use public folders and yes i would like everybody to be able to access them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to mail enable the PF in ESM. The PF will be assigned an email address based on your Default Recipient Policy, but the email address can be changed if needed. You'll need to make sure the Anonymous and Default entities have the Contributor role on the PF in order to recieve email to the PF.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/mf021.html) is a pretty decent step-through of what you're trying to accomplish.  It's for Exchange 2000, but the steps should be the same for 2003.